# Opening a file on a server with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So I am working on a ASP.NET web application, and using VB for the code behind. I have a GridView with a HyperLinkField that contains a path to the file on server.

Current Format:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="var1", "var2" DataTextField="var1" DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "\\server\...\fileName.doc">
```

However, when I run the project, and try to click on the hyperlink, nothing happens at all. I would like the file to be opened, or downloaded, when the hyperlink is pressed. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Your `DataNavigateUrlFields` is formatted incorrectly. You can't have two sets of double quotes for the value seperated by a common. In HTML, attributes must be formatted like `name="value"`. You're also missing the `runat="server"` attribute that is necessary for ASP.NET server side controls.

Comment: So I have made the changes you suggested, but clicking on the hyperlink, still does nothing. 
If the server which contains the file is remote, would I have to add something before the actual path on the server because I noticed when I hover over the link when running the application, the link is in the following format:
file://server/.../fileName.doc

Comment: Is the URL to the file correct? What happens if you copy the URL from the hyperlink and paste it in your browser?

Comment: If I manually input it into my web browser, it will download the file

Comment: The DataNavigateUrlFormatString is a format string and not the file that you will be displaying.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Okay, so then should I be setting the NavigateUrl to the address?